# Suma de campos Time en SQL Server

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, select, time

Supongamos que tengo estos campos `Time`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hago esta consulta pasa sumarlos:

```
SELECT campo,asignadoa,campo2,CAST(fecha AS VARCHAR) As fecha ,CAST(SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME)))   
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 )  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' +  
  CAST(( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' +  
  CAST(SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60 AS VARCHAR ) AS duracion, count(*) as Llamados FROM @Table GROUP BY asignadoa,campo,campo2,fecha ORDER BY Llamados DESC
```

Pero cuando el resultado por ejemplo es: `1 hora 3 minutos 1 segundo` el resultado es el siguiente `1:3:1` siendo que la manera correcta o como se pudiera ver mejor es `01:03:01`.

¿Saben como puedo hacerlo así?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganas bastante claridad y sencillez si incorporas el uso de una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para calcular en primer lugar la suma de cada tiempo, que en este caso lo hacemos sumando segundos de diferencia contra el tiempo inicial `'00:00:00.000'`, luego simplemente es ver esos segundos, cuantas horas, minutos y segundos representan.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select campo,
       asignadoa,
       campo2,
       CAST(fecha AS VARCHAR) As fecha,
       count(*) as Llamados,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(SS, '00:00:00.000', duracion)) AS SS
       FROM @Table 
       GROUP BY campo,
                asignadoa,
                campo2,
                fecha
) SELECT *, 
         RIGHT('0' + CAST(SS / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' +
         RIGHT('0' + CAST(SS % 3600 / 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' +
         RIGHT('0' + CAST(SS % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) as 'duracion'
    FROM CTE    
    ORDER BY Llamados DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la instrucción [RIGHT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para conseguir lo que buscas, de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT campo,asignadoa,campo2,CAST(fecha AS VARCHAR) As fecha ,
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME)))   
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 )  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +  
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +  
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS duracion, 
  count(*) as Llamados FROM @Table GROUP BY asignadoa,campo,campo2,fecha ORDER BY Llamados DESC
```

Lo que hace esta instrucción es poner, en este caso, `'00'` delante del resultado obtenido, por ejemplo `'2'`, y entonces te selecciona los caracteres específicados en el segundo argumento de la instrucción `RIGHT` desde la derecha, en este caso `2`, es decir, que de `'002'` te va a cojer `'02'`, y esto lo hacemos con los 3 valores que obtenemos, hora, minutos y segundos.

[Fiddle donde he hecho las pruebas.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cbcc8/4)

---

EDIT:

Para poder obtener mas de 3 digitos de hora deberías hacer una comprobación de si la hora que te devuelve es mas pequeña que 2 caracteres para aplicar el `RIGHT` o no aplicarlo, para ello usamos `CASE`.

La consulta quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT campo,asignadoa,campo2,CAST(fecha AS VARCHAR) As fecha , 
CASE WHEN LEN(CAST(SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME)))   
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 )  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS VARCHAR)) < 2 THEN 
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME)))   
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 )  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) 
  ELSE CAST(SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME)))   
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 )  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS VARCHAR) 
  END + ':' +  
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60  
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +  
  RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(duracion AS DATETIME))) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS duracion
  FROM @Table GROUP BY asignadoa,campo,campo2,fecha ORDER BY Llamados DESC
```

[Nuevo fiddle donde he hecho la prueba.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cbcc8/9)

Comment: Hola Marc, Gracias por la respuesta, al hacer pruebas me di cuenta que si las horas son mas de 100 me elimina el primer numero:
Resultado real: 146:56:55
Resultado con Right:  46:56:55

Comment: @Richard Te he editado la respuesta añadiendo como hacerlo